# How to run a local script with a multiple-word argument on a remote server?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to run the script `test.sh` (which is on my local machine) on a remote server. `test.sh` takes an argument that often has multiple words.

test.sh:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while getopts b: opt;
do
  case $opt in
    b)
       bval="$OPTARG"
       ;;
  esac
done
echo $bval
```

It works fine on my local machine:

```
./test.sh -b "multi word arg"
```

Output:

```
multi word arg
```

But when I run it on a remote server, like so:

```
ssh -A user@remotehost "bash -s" -- < ./test.sh -b "multi word arg"
```

I get only:

```
multi
```

Any ideas on how I could pass the full, multi-word argument to the script?

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450020/executing-sh-c-script-through-ssh-passing-arguments-safely-and-sanely

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205567/how-to-execute-an-arbitrary-simple-command-over-ssh-without-knowing-the-login-sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another level of quotes: `'"multi word arg"'`

The first level of quotes is removed by your local shell, and `ssh` gets `multi word arg`. Then `ssh`, on the remote system, runs something like `$SHELL -c "bash -s -- -b multi word arg"` (where `$SHELL` is your login shell, most probably bash, again).The login shell then does quote removal (none to be removed) and word splitting, which is why you get one word.

To illustrate:

```
% ssh 192.168.0.2 'printf :%s:\\n' '"foo bar baz"'
:foo bar baz:
% ssh 192.168.0.2 'printf :%s:\\n' 'foo bar baz'
:foo:
:bar:
:baz:
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm hoping to run a full script that is stored locally on a remote server, which (AFAIK) requires the `"bash -s" -- < ./test.sh -b "multi word arg"` syntax. Using that syntax, when I wrapped "multi word arg" in an extra set of quotes, like so: `'"multi word arg"'`, the output was an empty string - the `-b` flag didn't even get triggered. Is there an alternative to my syntax that would allow me to use the extra quote wrapping?

Comment: @JacobStern I get `multi word arg` as the output. Something else might messing with your command there. O.o Maybe try `bash -xs` to get debug output and update your question with that.

Comment: You're right, this totally works! I realized I dropped the '--' when I ran the command, which was what caused it to fail. Your answer works perfectly.

Comment: One follow-up question - is there any way to do this if `"multi word arg"` is stored in a variable, like `PHRASE="multi word arg"`? (My full use case is to run this command within a shell script). When I try wrapping a variable in single quotes, (`'$PHRASE'` it treats the variable as a string literal rather than as a variable, and when I wrap the variable in double quotes (`"$PHRASE"`), it ignores the quotes and I get "multi" as output. Is this worth a new question?

Comment: @JacobStern you can swap the quotes around, perhaps: `"'$PHRASE'"`, or use parameter expansion with quoting: `"${PHRASE@Q}"`

Comment: Those both work! Thank you again. I'm going to ask a new question because the **full** use case requires multiple ssh tunnels, and that breaks this again, but that goes beyond the original question. [Here is the new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/573322/how-to-run-a-local-script-with-whitespace-in-arguments-on-a-remote-machine-throu)