# how do I escape quote in ssh command?

Tags: bash, ssh

we can run command via ssh:

```
$ ssh user@host bash -c "'echo x '"
x
```

However I found that I cannot escape `'`:

```
$ ssh user@host bash -c "'echo \''"
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I also tried `\\` and `\\\`, `\\\\`, nothing works.

the idea is to pass things like `ls -1tr /var/log/ | head -10 | xargs -d '\n' -I {} echo {}`. But the `\'` does not work so I do not know how to pass the `'\n'`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try doubling your backslash. It will pass a single backslash down one level of interpretation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450020/executing-sh-c-script-through-ssh-passing-arguments-safely-and-sanely

Comment: To quote a string that includes single quotes you can escape the single quotes outside pairs of single quotes with a backslash, e.g. for `foo'bar` use `'foo'\''bar'`. You might have to double the backslashes. Try `"'ls -1tr /var/log/ | head -10 | xargs -d '\\''\\n'\\'' -I {} echo {}'"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you find yourself in quoting hell, heredocs often help

```bsh
ssh user@host bash <<END
echo \'
END
```

That being said, there is no way for a single quoted string to contain a single quote

Comment: The limitation is that if the passed script needs to do user interaction, the standard input is now used by the script itself. Also, you don't need to invoke `bash` explicitly if the remote shell is `bash` (we don't know what the remote shell is though).

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel internally quotes strings multiple times. You can use the quoting engine with:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
write your string here, which may contain ' or " or \n
ctrl-D
```

If you need it quoted twice:

```
parallel --shellquote --shellquote
```

For fun:

```
echo "'" | parallel --shellquote --shellquote --shellquote --shellquote --shellquote --shellquote
```