# how to run ssh command and let the variable get expanded remotely

Tags: bash, ssh, variable

I expect following this command to expand the HOME variable on the remote server:

```
ssh user@host bash -c "'echo ${HOME}'"
```

but instead this is expanded locally.

How do I get the remote HOME variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the purpose is to just get the remote value of the `HOME` environment variable, it would be easier to do

```
ssh user@host printenv HOME
```

This would work as long as the remote shell or system has the `printenv` utility.

---

The `HOME` variable is being expanded locally because it is in a double-quoted string.

Instead, do either

```
ssh user@host 'bash -c "echo \"\$HOME\""'
```

or

```
ssh user@host 'bash -c '"'"'echo "$HOME"'"'"
```

In the first case above, the remote shell gets the command

```
bash -c "echo \"\$HOME\""
```

to execute.

In the second, it gets

```
bash -c 'echo "$HOME"'
```

If your local shell is `zsh` or `bash`, then you can use the `%q` format specifier of `printf` to construct a properly quoted string for the remote shell:

```
ssh user@host "$( printf '%q ' bash -c 'echo "$HOME"' )"
```

This also works for multi-line commands:

```
ssh user@host "$( printf '%q ' bash -c '
echo "home: $HOME"
echo "away: $AWAY"' )"
```

See also:

- [Executing `sh -c` script through SSH (passing arguments safely and sanely)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450020/executing-sh-c-script-through-ssh-passing-arguments-safely-and-sanely)

Comment: how can I do the same thing with multiline command? in `ssh user@host bash <<END`

Comment: @Wang Your example is not a complete command. If you want to run a script, then transfer it over and run it. Otherwise, you may use `printf` as I showed in my answer.

Comment: @Wang Assuming you don't need to do any user interaction in your script, then just let the remote shell read the commands. If the remote shell is `bash`, then it should be enough with redirecting into `ssh user@host` (no special invocation of `bash` necessary).